# Odd definition of method with "async" and return type nongeneric "Task"?

Tags: c#

A method defined as below cannot return anything. So how does it fit
into the normal syntax that such a method has to return "Task".
For this reason, the method below will not compile when "async" is removed.

```
static async Task MyAsyncMethod() { }
```

Also when you call the method with:

```
await MyAsyncMethod();
```

"await" is supposed to be called on awaitable object, but here the return
type is "struct Void" which is not awaitable

Comment: It will compile if async is removed, if you actually return a Task. Not that I recommend doing so in most circumstances. Anyways, what's your actual question? I see a question mark in your title, but not actual question. Just an observation.

Comment: You return a `Task` because that's how the runtime can determine when the asynchronous operation completes. If you simply mark it `void`, while it will compile, it will be treated as "fire and forget", and you have no way to wait on that task to complete before performing some other logic. Fire and forget semantics are reserved for event handlers (e.g. button clicks).

Comment: The point is syntax consistency. When the syntax says to return "Task" but the in reality it depends on other modifiers then we we need to explain it

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: `async` doesn't fit with the normal syntax, it lifts the return value into a `Task<T>` for methods which return a value, or `Task` for void methods. `async` methods can also return `void` in which case the created `Task` is not returned to the caller and cannot be observed.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'The return type is "struct Void" which is not awaitable'?

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
public async Task DoAsync()
{
    // do anything synchron here
    // await other Task
}
```

or

```
public Task DoAsync()
{
    // do anything synchron here
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

or

```
public Task DoAsync()
{
    // do anything synchron here
    return Task.FromResult( false );
}
```